# Missing "</style>" in html source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to append style to html head with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var appendStyle = jQuery('<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}</style>');
jQuery('html > head').append(appendStyle);
</script>
```

The problem is that  is missing in html. Html source (ctrl + u) will show this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var appendStyle = '<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}';
jQuery('html > head').append(appendStyle);
</script>
```

It is weird because this happens only on some pages. Is there anything wrong with my code?  Has anybody any idea why '' is cut off?

Comment: It's working as intended for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/nkk291mm/

Comment: It is also working on all other websites. Only on one website it doesn't work and it doesn't matter which borwser I use. I have no idea what could cut </style> off from html source.

Answer (score 2):

#### Appending Entire Stylesheets

If you want to append an entire style sheet use: (Make sure you have your styles in `style.css` already).

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>');
```

---

#### Update single element style

If you only want to update the style for 1 element (say `body`), you don't need to add it into the head, instead just apply the style directly to the element (It will show inline).

```
$('body').css('margin', 0); // Apply this style directly to the element
```

---

#### Adding multiple elements into the head

If you have to use the approach you are, you may consider escaping the backslash in the `</style>`.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Also remember the DOM ready when using jQuery! (You may have issues without it)
$(document).ready(function(){
    var appendStyle = jQuery('<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}<\/style>');
    jQuery('html > head').append(appendStyle);
})
</script>
```

Comment: The styles are generated within html, I can not change this. The above scenario was just example, multiple style rules are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var appendStyle = '<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}';
    $('html > head').append(appendStyle);
});
```

Shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    var appendStyle = '<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}';
    $('html > head').append(appendStyle);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is not when the code is executed, the problem is that something cut off '</style>' from html source and this prevent style to be applied.

Comment: Better you can use css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. This will reset your all HTML element styles.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. It seems there is some javascript code which cut off any ending tag. Even if I put

```
var example = '</example>'
```

it will cut if off. So what I did is that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var appendStyle = jQuery('<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}</'+'style>');
  jQuery('html > head').append(appendStyle);
  </script>
```

Comment: if only i had seen this sooner! I had the same problem and solved by escaping the forward slash character

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let everyone know that it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a class

```
.body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

and include jquery

```
$('body').addClass('body');
```